# Play Framework 2.2 - Error when creating Form of model class with name Request

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

If I create a model class like this:

```
case class Request(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, title: String, url:String, description: Option[String])

object Request {
  ...
}
```

And then try creating a view with this header:

```
@(endpointForm: Form[Request],message: String)
```

I receive the following error when compiling:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - reference to Request is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by `import play.api.mvc._` and `import models._`

But if I change the name of the model class it works fine. In the end I decided to change the name of my class, but I still wonder why that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request` already exists and is already defined under package `play.api.mvc`.

If you don't want to change the name of your model, you should refer to it as `models.Request` to eliminate any ambiguity vis-a-vis `play.api.mvc.Request`.